# Allow android 4 devices to connect to Apache HTTPS

Tags: apache-http-server, android, ssl, https

I recently renewed the HTTPS site certificate on the server I maintain for a cient and, while installing, tightened up apache ssl settings, specifically, supported protocols and ciphers (e.g. I finally removed SSL3, etc.)

Unfortunately, within an hour I had phone calls from the client complaining of a problem. The client has a field base of sales people (around 50 of them all over the USA and Canada) that use company issued Android tablets with a custom order entry and customer tracking application.  That application stopped working - and my client is now unable to receive orders.  This is rather critical, as they are over $100K behind on order fulfilment just a day later.

The first thing I tracked is that the new root CA certificate is not trusted by default in Android 4 (DigiCert Global Root G2).  I installed that cert on a sample device I got - and now at least chrome can connect to the site.  However the app still can't connect to the server.  It throws "Connection closed by peer" error every time it tries to communicate with the server.

My guess is that the issue is with the supported cipher suite - I'm guessing, native android code doesn't support any of the ciphers that are installed on the server. Therefore I got two questions so far:

1. What ciphers do I need to enable on the server to allow android 4 native app to connect?  To the best of my knowledge, the app uses `java.net.HttpURLConnection` to connect to remove host.
2. What else do I need to look into/enable to try to get this working?

Please note that updating to a newer version of android is not an option, as the cost is way too prohibitive for my client. I have today and tomorrow (Saturday and Sunday) to resolve this issue - or the whole client's business is under risk.

**UPDATE:** here are the ciphers/protocols currently enabled:

```
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
```

Comment: Solution revert back to the previous configuration giving you time to debug the problem.  “What ciphers do I need to enable on the server to allow android 4 native app to connect?” - The ciphers you disabled.

Comment: @Ramhound Heh... easier said than done.  In my overzealous mind, I just changed the set up without looking or backing up what it was before...

Comment: If you can't tell us what you did, it will be difficult to help you, in the timeframe you have.  Of course your timeframe won't have any affect when you receive an answer.

Comment: @Ramhound of course, that I understand.  However I could rephrase the question as "I now need to get android 4 apps to connect to this server - what ciphers/protocols do I need to enable"?

Comment: You haven’t told us what ciphers are enabled.  Only you stopped using SSL3

Comment: @Ramhound That's a very good point - I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-note: I do have a sample device with the app in question running on it.

Ok, so after hours of struggling, in a fit of desperation, I started changing the settings in the app to point it to various other servers that I have access to - and I finally got one, where connection worked - so I copied protocol and cipher settings from that server to the one in question, changed the settings in the app to point back to the original server - and it worked.

For reference, here are the settings:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:!DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:!DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:!DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!DHE-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA:!DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:!DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:!DHE-DSS-CBC-SHA:!DHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
```

I have to settle for SSL Labs score dropping from A+ to A- as I had to include weak ciphers, but that's understandable. Also, for some reason, the initial connection takes very long (several seconds) - but at least the orders can be sent :)